# Append Open List from Dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, append

I have created a csv file containing zip codes and corresponding vendors in those zip codes.

[CSV File Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIOeA.png)

**Download CSV:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hm6yvy9gviydcv/us_postal_codes.csv?dl=0

I wrote some code to convert this into a dictionary. What I want have is an input zip code prompt so that the program spits out the corresponding dictionary data in a new dataframe. I tried using the append function below with an open set, but it is not running properly.Novice to python, so any suggestions on how to do this efficiently are greatly appreciated.

**please see below:**

```
python
import sys
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
cwd
os.chdir("/Users/PRAnthony/Desktop")

from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import pandas as pd 

file1 = r'us_postal_codes.csv'
df_1 = pd.read_csv(file1, index_col=0)
dic = df_1.to_dict()

zipcode = input("Insert Zip ")

vendors = []
for row in df_1['zip'] :
    if row == zipcode :
        vendors.append(dic.get(zipcode))

print(vendors)
```

---

Comment: I do not understand your question... can you provide a [mcve]? Images of csv-files are not very helpful...

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data.  Post a portion of the data and format it as code.

Comment: That's the code I am running, I inserted a link to the csv